# UITextView not fitting to content

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, uitextview

I am using this code to create a UITextView that is suppose to fit within a UIView container:

```
// Make the cellTextView.
let cellTextView = UITextView()
cellTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
cellTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cellTextView.scrollEnabled = false
superview.addSubview(cellTextView)

// Constrain the cellTextView.
cellTextView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.topAnchor, constant: 8).active = true
cellTextView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).active = true
cellTextView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).active = true
cellTextView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).active = true
```

But it is producing this result:
[image: Look at the padding]

This is what it should look like:
[image: No padding]

I have tried a lot of different things, but nothing fixes it.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are your image constraints?

Comment: The image is not affecting the text view. That is because the hierarchy is like this: ImageView (Background), ContainerBar (Overlaid above ImageView), UITextView(Inside ContainerBar). The ContainerBar expands and shrinks as needed to fit the UITextView, but I'm guessing the UITextView's intrinsic content size is a bit more then required. The image constraints are just set to each side so it fills.

Comment: What an easy fix... All I had to do was get rid of the constants, and now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the constants that you're using as margins. That will fix it.

```
// Make the cellTextView.
let cellTextView = UITextView()
cellTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
cellTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cellTextView.scrollEnabled = false
superview.addSubview(cellTextView)

// Constrain the cellTextView.
cellTextView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.topAnchor).active = true
cellTextView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.bottomAnchor).active = true
cellTextView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.leadingAnchor).active = true
cellTextView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.trailingAnchor).active = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set height constraint

```
  // Constrain the cellTextView.
    cellTextView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.topAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
    cellTextView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
    cellTextView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).active = true
    cellTextView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(superview.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).active = true         

    cellTextView.sizeToFit()
    cellTextView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(self.cellTextView.contentSize.height).active = true
```

also you may try to call

```
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```